# Running a "sudo" command from a PHP script?

Tags: php, linux, sudo

I want to run a "sudo" command from the PHP and I have read all the tutorials on the web, but no solution works. At least I've added the default "nobody" user of LAMP to the root group – but no effect.

```
echo exec("sudo echo hi");
```

**A note on security:**

While some people here are downvoting this due to their strong belief that this will create a big security hole that will destroy the entire Internet, there are some valid cases for this, e.g., in testing. Running setup scripts from PHPUnit / Behat suites to configure the environment may require sudo permission. Those scripts are not accessible from the application and do not create security holes, as the matter of fact they help to ensure such holes are not present.

Comment: do not do that. it's a huge security hole.

Comment: should not encourage others by this type of question as this creates big security issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding users to the root group does not give them sudo rights, that is what /etc/sudoers is for.

To be honest, what you're trying to do sounds like a giant security hole

EDIT: copied from comments...

My suggestion would be something like, setting up a cron under the root user, that checks against a file or db that your PHP can write to, parses it, and remove the users you've specified.

Comment: Well, I thought of creating a biiig, big security hole and I surely wanted to avoid this! So you see how desperate I am :-D
May you give me **a good** and safe solution?

(Just for informational reason: I am trying to add and remove FTP users with php..)

Comment: All you've told us is that you want to run a command. Without knowing what you're trying to accomplish, how can we try and point you at a better solution?

Comment: My question was, how can I run a sudo cmd! Thats true.. The reason why I wanted to know that, was the ftp user thing.. I wrote this, just to give you information on **what** my plans are, because you told me about the security hole and I think you are right! And perhaps you can give me a hint on how to solve my problem..

Comment: My suggestion would be something like, setting up a cron under the root user, that checks against a file or db that your PHP can write to, parses it, and remove the users you've specified.

Comment: oouh.. To be honest I have never heared about that :D. You mean a "cronjob"? Is it difficult to connect a cronjob with a database?

Comment: Shouldn't be, you can generally use db cli commands to output specific queries to STDOUT iirc.

Comment: Does db cli belong to SQLite?

Comment: No, there are CLI tools for most major vendors, PostgreSQL (psql), MySQL (mysql) and SQLite (sqlite3).

Comment: aah, so CLI stands for Command-Line? However.. I have "Lampp" installed, and the "mysql db399" cmd just says that the programm >>mysql<< is not installed yet o__O?!? But it definitely is! I dunno but, is the mysql-client lib required? (well i think so :D?)

Comment: That is probably worth bringing up separately.

Comment: okay now I know how to add a new "cron". It works perfectly, BUT I dont get it, how to retrieve data out of the database and create a user according to the retrieved data.. you know what I mean :/?

Comment: I think there are other people better suited to answer that. Perhaps open a new question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should run chmod u+s on your script. Or maybe ug+s (Depending on your need). This way you will have su access.

Answer (score 0):

you should add your web-server user to `/etc/sudoers` file

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

You first need to find the user of your webserver and give them root privialges, the above code will tell you this, but as others say THIS IS A MASSIVE SECURITY HOLE and I strongly do not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

All the security stuff aside, this is possible. Indeed as Jon Stirling has stated, adding users to a specific group is not going to help you. You need to specify the correct sudo lines with "visudo" as root, eg:

```
nobody ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/echo hi
```

This will let the user root, execute the command "/usr/bin/echo hi" as the user root.

Now for executing it via PHP:

```
echo exec("/usr/bin/sudo -u root /usr/bin/echo hi");
```